# Modify file date-time attributes

Tags: windows, file-attributes

I want to modify the date-time file attributes "*Created*", "*Modified*" and "*Accessed*". The file is located in NTFS filesystem on Windows 7. I have found several freeware utilities that promise to do that but I do not want to install a new software just because one simple change. Is there a possibility to change these attributes without installing a 3rd party tool?

Well, I could change the system time, then modify the file and return the system time back but I believe there must be a more elegant way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows does not offer this. but any decent file manager can do that. Don't you use anything like Total Commander or any file manager whatsoever ? Explorer is limited in unimaginable ways.
You could change it with shell as described [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/06/01/use-powershell-to-modify-file-access-time-stamps.aspx). But its much more convenient to run a file manager, just select the files and change what you want.

Comment: Problem is the brackets around the link, that got included in the link somehow. Correct link: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/06/01/use-powershell-to-modify-file-access-time-stamps.aspx

Comment: Powershell is a good hint. It works for me.